# Data Pump Incremental Export

Tags: oracle, datapump

I have to perform a incremental export in oracle using Data Pump API. I read somewhere that Data Pump API does not support incremental backup. Is there any alternatives to this? I have to perform the export using the Data Pump API.

Answer (score 0):

you cannot perform incremental data pumps. If you want to do incremental backups then your best option is RMAN.

There use to be an "`inctype`" flag in version 8 of oracle, but this was removed in version 9.

Dave